# Select object from within collection

Tags: scripting, collections

Can anyone tell me how I can choose an arbitrary object from within a collection? My script leaves me with nothing active (or selected) at one point, but I need something to be active.

I have the collection name from this:

```
Coll = bpy.data.collections.get('Structure')
```

So I can do something like this:

```
if Coll:
   for obj in Coll.objects:
       obj.select_set(True)
```

Which makes each object active one at a time, leaving me with the last one active at the end of the loop. But that seems pretty heavy handed. There must be a neater way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this work?

```
from random import choice

# deselect all:
for obj in Coll.objects: obj.select_set(False)
# choose one and select it:
rnd_obj = choice(Coll.objects)
rnd_obj.select_set(True)
```

Comment: Alternatively after choice and without deselecting all first `for obj in Coll.objects: obj.select_set(obj is rnd_obj)`  _and to set as active_ `context.view_layer.objects.active = rnd_obj`

Comment: Great! I've ended up with this, thanks to you both: import bpy

Coll = bpy.data.collections.get('Collection')

from random import choice

rnd_obj = choice(Coll.objects)

for obj in Coll.objects: obj.select_set(obj is rnd_obj)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = rnd_obj